# Switching between screens in React Native leading to inconsistent data

Tags: android, react-native, api

I am building a small ecommerce android app using React Native. This App has three tabs:
Home
Profile
Orders

The implementation is such that when i open the App the Home screen loads , it makes an API call to fetch some user details and then these are stored in a cache. These user details are throughout my App will be used in Orders screen to fetch the orders placed by the user. But the issue that i am facing is that if i open my App and i quickly jump to Orders screen , i am unable to get the orders placed by the user because i jumped quickly and because of which API call didnt get complete and hence no data in the cache.
Can anyone suggest me how can i go about fixing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Best way of solving this issue is to make the api call while the splash screen is showing, meaning, before letting the user interact with your app. If you're using Expo, you can use the [`AppLoading`](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/app-loading/) component.

```js
const handleAppInit = async () => {
    // Make the api calls here, be sure to make it async so 
    // the function does not resolve before the api call is done.
};

<AppLoading
    startAsync={handleAppInit}
    onFinish={() => setAppLoading(false)}
    onError={console.warn}
/>
```